# custom arguments to npm start with webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

I have configured an angular2 project with Webpack as my module bundler. I have everything working and now I want to take it to real world, where I want to pass theme and environment as arguments to my NPM commands. Below is my current package.json script config.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

To explain further, when I execute "npm start --theme=themeA --environment=UAT" I should be able to access the values of "theme" and "environment" in my ts file (say config.ts). Rightnow I have hardcode the values, so when I change themeA to themeB in config.ts the output generated is for themeB. But I wish to make it as command line driven. 
So, in a nut-shell,
1. How to pass custom parameters to NPM commands.
2. How to access the values in js.
Note:I want to do it for both npm start and npm build.

Answer (score 0):

The main concern you should use "double dash" for the end of options of the command. See here [answer about --](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash)

I did the next ones:

```
scripts": {
    //this is for nodejs memory limit
    "build": "node ./tools/bundle --max_old_space_size=4096",
    //this arguments will be thrown to the start.js
    "start": "node ./tools/start -- verbose release no-compile",
}
```

And control options (arguments) in start.js:

```
var options = {
    release: process.argv.indexOf('release') !== -1,
    noCompile: process.argv.indexOf('no-compile') !== -1,
    start: process.argv.indexOf('start') !== -1,
    verbose: process.argv.indexOf('verbose') !== -1,
};
```